# Need to pass extra values apart from the payload in msmq

Tags: c#, msmq, msmq-transaction

All,

I need to pass extra values apart from the Body of the MSMQMessage class, is there a way to do this ?

I understand that i can create a complex object and use that, but want to check if there are any other properties that i can use to pass few custom values on the MSMQmesasge class.

Thanks -Nen

Answer (score 1):

How about using the message label as a small data store?

Comment: good idea, but  MSMQMessage.Extensions property looks promising,

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, you can also use AppSpecific field, altough it's just an int.

Comment: What's your take on .extension property of the message queue class?

Comment: Extension shares 4MB limit with Body. You can only access it as a byte array array from .Net, so you'll need some simple decoding if you need just single string or int. And it's not visible at all from Computer Management, you'll probably need some third party utility for debugging purposes. Apart from that, I don't see another reason not to use it if you need more than basic additional content.